# Create NAs for first two rows using group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to replace my observations with NAs. I would like to replace NAs only for the first two observations with respect to each group represented by a given ID.

So from:

```
      id          b
1     1  0.1125294
2     1 -0.6871102
3     1  0.1721639
4     2  0.2714921
5     2  0.1012665
6     2 -0.3538989
```

Get:

```
      id          b
1     1  NA
2     1  NA
3     1  0.1721639
4     2  NA
5     2  NA
6     2 -0.3538989
```

Tried this, but it does not work...

```
data<- data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(data$b[1:2] = NA)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use `replace`... something like `mutate(b = replace(b, head(b, 2), NA)`. Also have in mind that you should not use `data$` in a pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:2, each = 3), value = rnorm(6))
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(value=replace(value, 1:2, NA))
```

Comment: Where are you using `bindr` in your solution?

Comment: I don't know. But could it be that `replace()` depends on it? I got an error before I installed it.

Comment: Nope...most likely something wrong with your session... do `gc()` and try again maybe...

Comment: Right. It works without `bindr`. I removed the package and started a new session and it is working.